# External harddrive partition table lost after each Xubuntu 10.04 reboot

Tags: partitioning, xubuntu

I have a problem with my USB external hardrive. Each time I plug it in my Xubuntu 14.04 server, the partition table of the harddrive is lost.
I have to restore a MBR backup each time to get it back functionnal.

The problem doesn't happen when the drive is plugged into a Windows or with my TV. It's also ok when the harddrive is plugged when the Xubuntu is already running. The partition disappear only after a reboot with the harddrive connected.

Here is a dmesg of the reboot :

```
[    3.136068] ata6: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[    3.357106] scsi 7:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WD       My Book 1130     1012 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[    3.357846] scsi 7:0:0:1: Enclosure         WD       SES Device       1012 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[    3.358158] sd 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[    3.358334] scsi 7:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg4 type 13
[    3.358841] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] 732558336 4096-byte logical blocks: (3.00 TB/2.72 TiB)
[    3.359466] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[    3.359471] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 47 00 10 08
[    3.360082] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
[    3.360086] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[    3.361229] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] 732558336 4096-byte logical blocks: (3.00 TB/2.72 TiB)
[    3.362451] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
[    3.362454] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[    3.792756] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    6.621546] random: nonblocking pool is initialized
[   10.356947] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Invalid command failure
[   10.356951] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc]
[   10.356953] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[   10.356956] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc]
[   10.356958] Sense Key : Illegal Request [current]
[   10.356962] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc]
[   10.356965] Add. Sense: Invalid field in cdb
[   10.356968] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB:
[   10.356970] Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00
[   10.356978] end_request: critical target error, dev sdc, sector 0
[   10.356981] Buffer I/O error on device sdc, logical block 0
[   12.204375] ldm_validate_partition_table(): Disk read failed.
[   12.204391] Dev sdc: unable to read RDB block 0
[   12.205230]  sdc: unable to read partition table
[   12.207726] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] 732558336 4096-byte logical blocks: (3.00 TB/2.72 TiB)
[   12.209701] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
[   12.209704] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[   12.209708] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
[   12.210746] ses 7:0:0:1: Attached Enclosure device
```

A fdisk :

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 3000.6 GB, 3000558944256 bytes
255 têtes, 63 secteurs/piste, 45599 cylindres, total 732558336 secteurs
Unités = secteurs de 1 * 4096 = 4096 octets
Taille de secteur (logique / physique) : 4096 octets / 4096 octets
taille d'E/S (minimale / optimale) : 4096 octets / 4096 octets
Identifiant de disque : 0x2052474d

Périphérique Amorçage  Début         Fin      Blocs    Id. Système
/dev/sdb1   *         256   536870655  2147481600    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb2       536876235   732547934   782686800    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

Anybody has an idea to explain since strange behavior?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried different USB ports and/or cable? And what sort of hardrive is it?

Comment: USB cable is the same on used on Xubuntu and Windows (no problem with Windows). I tried other ports but same issue. The harddrive is a Western Digital My Essential 3To : http://www.wdc.com/en/products/products.aspx?id=260

Comment: If it's not a Windows bootable drive, could you back up all data, create a GPT partition table and restore all data and see whether this happens again?  (I'm suspecting an error in the MBR which Windows can handle but Linux not)